# "getElementByTagName" to add nodes to a list

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a list item to my Ordered list by capturing the list item in javaScript using 'getElementByTagName' but it is giving error:

`list.appendChild is not a function`

```js
{
    let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    let list = document.getElementsByTagName("ol");
    btn.onclick = function(){
        let node = document.createElement("li").appendChild(document.createTextNode("new item"));
        list.appendChild(node);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>My Website</title>
  <script defer src = "js/index.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <ol id="items">
    <li class="border">Home</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li class="border" id="special">About us</li>
  </ol>
  <button id="btn"> Click me</button><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: The code does not give an error if I capture the 'ol' using getElementbyId but I want to know why I'm getting an error with 'getElementByTagName'.

Comment: You'll note that `getElementsByTagName` is plural, it returns an HTMLCollection, not an individual element. To do it this way you would need to access the element in the collection. `let list = document.getElementsByTagName("ol")[0];` or with desctructuring `let [list] = document.getElementsByTagName("ol");`

Comment: Think of the result of `getElementsByTagName` loosely as an array. You can't do `[myObj].myMethod()` because that will call the `myMethod` of the array object and not the method of the object held by the array.